# Getting blank response on invoking Rest API thur java code but thur postman working fine

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, postman, rest

In postman, I am calling a RestAPI. I have selected Basic Auth and passing username and password. It is working. I am getting response. But when I run it thru Java code and do authentication using Base64 encoding, I am getting blank response. Snapshots are attached below:

[Calling RestAPI thru Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJNb8.png)

Java code to do the same is below:

```
public static String doPOSTCall(String postUrl, String authorization, JSONObject jo) throws Exception {
        String output = "";
        CloseableHttpClient httpClientPO = (HttpClients.createDefault());
        HttpPost httpPostPO = new HttpPost(postUrl);

        String auth = "ts_impl" + ":" + "Oracle@123";

        byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(
                  auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
                String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
                httpPostPO.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);
        
        
        //httpPostPO.setHeader("Authorization", authorization);
        httpPostPO.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
        jo.writeJSONString(out);
        String reqJsonString = out.toString();

        System.out.println("json2 is " + reqJsonString);
        StringEntity entityPO = new StringEntity(reqJsonString);

        System.out.println("Request : " + httpPostPO);

        httpPostPO.setEntity(entityPO);

        HttpResponse responsePO = httpClientPO.execute(httpPostPO);
        HttpEntity entityFromResponse = responsePO.getEntity();

        if (entityFromResponse != null) {

            output = EntityUtils.toString(responsePO.getEntity());
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started working. The problem was that I was using http link in the code, where as it should have been https.

Answer (score 0):

You can to create the encoded header like this:

```
String authHeader = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple REST Client, You can try the below code :

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.Builder;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration; 


    public class RestClient {
 
        public static void main(String args[]){
             
            String url = "Give-Your-URL-here";
            String name = "username";
            String password = "password";
            String authorization = name + ":" + password;
            
            JSONObject jo; // Create your Object 
            // Do the necessary stuffs with the jo object, feeding data etc.


            String response = doPOSTCall(url, String authorization, JSONObject jo);        
            System.out.println("response: "+response);
        }
    
        public static String doPOSTCall(String postUrl, String authorization, JSONObject jo) throws Exception {
            
            // Authentication Part
            String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authorization.getBytes());
            System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);
            
            // JSON to String
            StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
            jo.writeJSONString(out);
            String reqJsonString = out.toString();    
            System.out.println("json2 is " + reqJsonString);
            
            //REST calling
            Client restClient = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(url);
            ClientResponse resp = webResource.accept("application/json")
                                             .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
                                             .post(ClientResponse.class, reqJsonString);

            // Response Verification
            if(resp.getStatus() != 200){
                System.err.println("Unable to connect to the server");
            }
            
            String output = resp.getEntity(String.class);
            return output;
        }
}
```

Update :

```
Maven Dependencies :    


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. could you please tell what packages need to be imported and what mvn dependency

Comment: @JagratiAgrawal : Please check the update portion in my answer. Have updated the maven dependency also added the imports. Extra imports you may remove.

Comment: Getting error : Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity, and MIME media type, application/octet-stream, was not found

Comment: `StringEntity entityPO = new StringEntity(reqJsonString);`  Comment this out. And edit the rest call as this :  ` .post(ClientResponse.class, reqJsonString);`